# How to reset the values in a dependent dropdownlist when value of second dropdown is lesser than first

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I'm new to Jquery.  I have created two dropdownlists `min_cost` and `max_cost` using a Yii extension `combobox.`   Below is the code I used to create the combobox.

```
<?php
    $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'min_cost',
        // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
        'data' => Yii::app()->params['cost_resales'],
        'options' => array(
            'onSelect' => 'cost_change(item.value)',
            'allowText' => false,
        ),
        // Options passed to the text input
        'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min Cost', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
    ));
    /*
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'max_cost', array(), array('style'=>'width:120px'));
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'min_cost', Yii::app()->params['cost_min_resales'],
            array(
                'empty'=>'Choose one',
                'onchange'=>'alert(value);',
            )
        );
    */
?>

<?php
    $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'max_cost',
        // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
        'data' =>Yii::app()->params['cost_resales'],
        // options passed to plugin
        'options' => array(
            'allowText' => false,
        ),
        // Options passed to the text input
        'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Max Cost', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
    ));
    /*
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'max_cost', array(), array('style'=>'width:120px'));
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'max_cost', Yii::app()->params['cost_max_resales'],
            array(
                'empty'=>'Choose one',
                'onchange'=>'alert(value);',
            )
        );
    */
?>
```

Now, the above widget has generated the below HTML code.

```
<select id="SearchForm_min_cost_select" style="display: none;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="10 lakhs">10 lakhs</option>
    <option value="20 lakhs">20 lakhs</option>
    <option value="30 lakhs">30 lakhs</option>
    <option value="40 lakhs">40 lakhs</option>
    <option value="50 lakhs">50 lakhs</option>
    <option value="60 lakhs">60 lakhs</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="SearchForm_min_cost" name="SearchForm[min_cost]" style="width:70px" placeholder="Min Cost" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<button type="button" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" id="btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
</button> 
<select id="SearchForm_max_cost_select" style="display: none;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="10 lakhs">10 lakhs</option>
    <option value="20 lakhs">20 lakhs</option>
    <option value="30 lakhs">30 lakhs</option>
    <option value="40 lakhs">40 lakhs</option>
    <option value="50 lakhs">50 lakhs</option>
    <option value="60 lakhs">60 lakhs</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="SearchForm_max_cost" name="SearchForm[max_cost]" style="width:70px" placeholder="Max Cost" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<button type="button" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" id="btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
</button>
```

In the above code, the select tags with options are all hidden.
In first dropdownlist, I'm also calling a function that has the Jquery code to create dependency for the second menu. i.e if 10 lakhs is selected in first dropdownlist, then the options available in the second dropdownlist will be greater than the one selected in first one.  I used the below function to filter the values based on the selected value in the first one.

```
<script>
    function cost_change() {
        var $options = jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').children().clone();
        console.log("options",$options);
        var index = jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').find(':selected').index()+1;
        console.log("index",index);
        jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html($options).children(':lt('+index+')').remove();
    }
</script>
```

Now, this is working fine till now. But, I want to make a condition such that if max value(value selected in second dropdownlist) is lesser than first then the value of first should reset to the value equal to the value selected in second dropdownlist. How can I do this.
I used Jquery code to do this, but it is not recognizing the select element as it is hidden. What should I do when the elements are hidden.How can I call them in Javascript function.

Comment: Add a listener to the `change` event in the second one and in the handler check the current value of the fisrt one DDL and so change it if you have to

Comment: @sabotero I have done the same thing. Instead of mentioning in the script I have taken it as onselect in widget. Now I want to see if some thing can be done with jquery

Comment: check my answer below. You can change the event form `change` to `selected`.

Comment: @sabotero No it isn't working. I think because the select element generated as display:none. Nothing is recognised

Comment: Even with `display:none` jQuery recognize the select markup. It must be a conflict with 'Yii'.

Comment: Your have to see in the API reference of Yii if there is a way to get control over it in javaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#SearchForm_max_cost_select").on('change', function(){
  var secondDDL = $(this),
  firstDDL = $("#SearchForm_min_cost_select");

  if(firstDDL.val() > secondDDL.val()){
    firstDDL.val(secondDDL.val());
  }

});
```

Comment: The [onselect](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp) event is used when the user selects/highlights some text, say, in a input:text box. In drop-down menus the onchange event is used.

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want it to work?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JPrdG/)

```
$min = $('#SearchForm_min_cost_select');
$max = $('#SearchForm_max_cost_select');
$min.on('change', cost_change);
$max.on('change', cost_change2);
function cost_change2() {
    var minIndex = $min.find(':selected').index();
    var maxIndex = $max.find(':selected').index();
    if (minIndex>maxIndex) {
            $max[0].selectedIndex = minIndex;
    }
}
```

This function(cost_change2) is called whenever a value is selected from the second drop-down. You might want to call it within cost_change as well, because otherwise the user can Select 50Lakh in $min, then 60Lakh in $max and then change $min to 80Lakh(making min>max).